# Creating custom JSP tag for jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, custom-tag

I have a jquery datatable as initialized below:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
    var oTable = $('#paginatedTable').dataTable( {
            "bServerSide" :true,
            "sAjaxSource" :"/JQueryPagination/Myservlet",
            "bProcessing" :true,
            "sPaginationType" :"full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI" :false,
            "aoColumns" : [ {
                "sTitle" :"CBox",
                "mData" :"Name",
                "bSortable": false,
                "mRender" : function(data, type, full) {
                        return '<input type=\"checkbox\"  onClick= myCheckBoxSel(this); value="' + data + '"id="ChkBox">';
                }
            }, {
                "sTitle" :"Name",
                "mData" :"Name",
                "mRender" : function(data, type, full) {
                    return '<a href="/JQueryPagination/MyservletLink?Name=' +data+ '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            }, {
                "sTitle" :"Address",
                "mData" :"Address"
            }, {
                "sTitle" :"Town",
                "mData" :"Town"
            }
             ]
        });
    });
```

Now I would like to create a custom jsp tag that would generate the same initialization code for me. Something like this.

```
<custom:jDataTable id="custDataTable" tableName="paginatedTable" bProcessing = "true" bServerSide="true" sAjaxSource="/JQueryPagination/Myservlet" paginationType="full_numbers"/>
```

But here I'm not able to figure out how to specify the column definitions through the custom tag. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by separating the columnDefs from the initialization code. And passing the columndfs variable through the custom tag. Thank you.